# Minecraft - decorative and peaceful fish plugin for Bukkit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-bukkit

I'm making an aquarium for the city on our server (a big building with a glass tunnel). I'm going to fill it with water and put Squid and Silverfish in it. But I thought it would be better if we had more variety.
So does anyone know of a plugin for being able to spawn various peaceful fish? I've done some searching on BukkitDev but found nothing.

Comment: [Mo' Creatures](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/81771-147-mo-creatures-v451-with-elephants-mammoths-komodo-dragons-more-ostriches-better-jellyfish-more-fairy-horses/)?

Comment: won't silverfish drown?

Comment: Mo's creatures is a perfect mod for that actually.

Comment: Silverfish are not fish. They'll drown. @fredley, I think Mo' Creatures is the best and only answer. You should post that.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I'm looking for a Bukkit plugin, not a mod. I edited the question to specify as such.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Tropicraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/533512-147-tropicraft-v423-tropical-realm-palm-trees-volcanoes-beaches/) Mod. It comes with an entire fishing mechanic and a large variety of fishes and underwater creatures.

In addition provides Tropicraft an own [Aquarium](http://wiki.tropicraft.net/wiki/Aquarium) Container. This may be the kind of mod you search. But keep in mind, that the players will need a client side modification, because this is a mod and not a server side bukkit plugin.

Comment: No sorry, I am looking for a server side bukkit plugin, so everyone on the server will be able to see it without having to install anything.

Comment: @schtoker If you want players to see it without having them install a client mod, then you won't be able to have "variety." At best, you could find a mod that spawns already existing mobs into water -- but then you'd have underwater cows and the like.